# AWS ECS - Docker Container exited with code 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, taskdef

I am trying to start my docker containers using AWS ECS. When i run the task, i see the status as Pending and then immediately i see that my task status is in stopped. But when i try to run the same docker container manually by SSH into that box, i am able to start the container. I am not able to get my docker container up using the ECS agent. i also tried SSH into that box and looked at all the ECS logs which is not helpful in tracking down this issue. Here is what i did step by step

1. Created my docker containers locally and tested the same.
2. Uploaded the working docker container image to the AWS ECR by following the AWS getting started documentation for ECS.
3. Created task definition for my docker containers.
4. Created a cluster configuration to run my task
5. I ran the task and selected the cluster where the task should be running
6. I see that task status is pending and immediately status changed to stopped.

   I am not sure about how to troubleshoot this issue. Also from the AWS UI, i see that docker container exited with Exit 0.

Here is my task definition which i have created

**Task Definition JSON**

```
{
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth",
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null
    },
    {
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role",
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null
    }
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:####################:taskdefinition/app1:3",
  "networkMode": "bridge",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "revision": 3,
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::##################################:role/EC2ContainerServiceFullAccess",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "memory": 6000,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8091,
          "containerPort": 8091,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "hostname": null,
      "essential": true,
      "entryPoint": [
        "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "name": "tomcat-container",
      "ulimits": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "JAVA_OPTS",
          "value": "-Xms2G -Xmx2G"
        }
      ],
      "links": null,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "image": "##################################/app1:latest",
      "command": [
        "/bin/bash"
      ],
      "user": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "privileged": null,
      "memoryReservation": null
    },
    {
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "memory": 512,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8082,
          "containerPort": 8082,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "hostname": null,
      "essential": true,
      "entryPoint": [
        "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "name": "app2",
      "ulimits": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "environment": [],
      "links": null,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "image": "##################################/app2:latest",
      "command": [
        "/bin/bash"
      ],
      "user": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "privileged": null,
      "memoryReservation": null
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "volumes": [
    {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/usr/local/app1/"
      },
      "name": "hostToContainer"
    }
  ],
  "family": "app1"
}
```

I am kind of stuck with this issue. Does anyone see any other way to fix this issue ?

Note that i am able to bring my application up and running by manually running my docker containers by doing ssh into the EC2 instance. But doing this way, i have a problem of all the docker containers deployed into the EC2 instance is deleted when i stop the EC2 instance. So i think my problem will be solved if i am able to run the docker containers by running the task definition.

I am attaching the logs present in the ecs-agent.logs

```
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Waiting for any previous stops to complete module="TaskEngine" task="csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (NONE->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (NONE->RUNNING),]" seqnum="19"
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Wait over; ready to move towards status: RUNNING module="TaskEngine" task="csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (NONE->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (NONE->RUNNING),]"
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Pulling container cs_docServer_container(image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx) (NONE->RUNNING) concurrently. Task: csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (NONE->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (NONE->RUNNING),]
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Pulling container cs_tomcat_container(image2YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY) (NONE->RUNNING) concurrently. Task: csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (NONE->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (NONE->RUNNING),]
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Updating container reference cs_docServer_container in Image State - sha256:cde23d8e79adfa91d9068188bfc184abcc875aac07a0fd80311a2087eb4d196f
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Finished pulling container image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx in 153.23238ms. Task: csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (NONE->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (PULLED->RUNNING),]
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Updating container reference cs_tomcat_container in Image State - sha256:666425a4dd65d237e8a4c5210836e808aa3831d85d5f0e1856b36ed5920b8575
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Finished pulling container image2YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY in 522.620398ms. Task: csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (PULLED->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (PULLED->RUNNING),]
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Creating container module="TaskEngine" task="csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (PULLED->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (PULLED->RUNNING),]" container="cs_docServer_container(image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx) (PULLED->RUNNING)"
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Creating container module="TaskEngine" task="csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (PULLED->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (PULLED->RUNNING),]" container="cs_tomcat_container(image2YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY) (PULLED->RUNNING)"
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Created container name mapping for task arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 - cs_docServer_container -> ecs-csapps_td-2-csdocServercontainer-faaad4f5948cdde8d101
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Created container name mapping for task arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 - cs_tomcat_container -> ecs-csapps_td-2-cstomcatcontainer-da92c589a3da81c2ae01
2017-11-08T07:01:04Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
2017-11-08T07:01:05Z [INFO] Created docker container for task arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327: cs_docServer_container -> fa5de8ea4260647093a89b0524a3ed30ca7fd73862644406541ff21b83cd726a
2017-11-08T07:01:05Z [INFO] Redundant container state change for task csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (NONE->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (PULLED->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (CREATED->RUNNING),]: cs_docServer_container(image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx) (CREATED->RUNNING) to CREATED, but already CREATED
2017-11-08T07:01:05Z [INFO] Created docker container for task arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327: cs_tomcat_container -> 8825ec236146a35d08e9aafc4c83b66ced99c609c89fd96974c9279657568d66
2017-11-08T07:01:05Z [INFO] Redundant container state change for task csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (CREATED->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (CREATED->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (CREATED->RUNNING),]: cs_tomcat_container(image2YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY) (CREATED->RUNNING) to CREATED, but already CREATED
2017-11-08T07:01:05Z [INFO] Starting container module="TaskEngine" task="csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (CREATED->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (CREATED->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (CREATED->RUNNING),]" container="cs_tomcat_container(image2YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY) (CREATED->RUNNING)"
2017-11-08T07:01:05Z [INFO] Starting container module="TaskEngine" task="csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (CREATED->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (CREATED->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (CREATED->RUNNING),]" container="cs_docServer_container(image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx) (CREATED->RUNNING)"
2017-11-08T07:01:05Z [INFO] TaskHandler: batching container event: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 cs_tomcat_container -> RUNNING, Ports [{8080 80 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE
2017-11-08T07:01:05Z [INFO] Redundant container state change for task csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (CREATED->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (RUNNING->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (CREATED->RUNNING),]: cs_tomcat_container(image2YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY) (RUNNING->RUNNING) to RUNNING, but already RUNNING
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Task change event module="TaskEngine" event="{Attachment:<nil> TaskARN:arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 Status:RUNNING Reason: Containers:[] Task:csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (RUNNING->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (RUNNING->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (RUNNING->RUNNING),]}"
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: batching container event: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 cs_docServer_container -> RUNNING, Ports [{8080 81 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Adding event: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE] sent: false
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Sending task change: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE] sent: false
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Redundant container state change for task csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (RUNNING->RUNNING) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (RUNNING->RUNNING),cs_docServer_container (RUNNING->RUNNING),]: cs_docServer_container(image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx) (RUNNING->RUNNING) to RUNNING, but already RUNNING
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Stopping container, container: cs_docServer_container(image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx) (RUNNING->STOPPED), task: csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (RUNNING->STOPPED) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (STOPPED->STOPPED),cs_docServer_container (RUNNING->STOPPED),]
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Error retrieving stats for container 8825ec236146a35d08e9aafc4c83b66ced99c609c89fd96974c9279657568d66: context canceled
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Container 8825ec236146a35d08e9aafc4c83b66ced99c609c89fd96974c9279657568d66 is terminal, stopping stats collection
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: batching container event: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 cs_tomcat_container -> STOPPED, Exit 0, , Known Sent: RUNNING
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [WARN] Error converting stats for container fa5de8ea4260647093a89b0524a3ed30ca7fd73862644406541ff21b83cd726a: Invalid container statistics reported
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Task change event module="TaskEngine" event="{Attachment:<nil> TaskARN:arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 Status:STOPPED Reason: Containers:[] Task:csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (STOPPED->STOPPED) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (STOPPED->STOPPED),cs_docServer_container (STOPPED->STOPPED),]}"
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Error retrieving stats for container fa5de8ea4260647093a89b0524a3ed30ca7fd73862644406541ff21b83cd726a: context canceled
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: batching container event: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 cs_docServer_container -> STOPPED, Exit 0, , Known Sent: RUNNING
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Adding event: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 -> STOPPED, Known Sent: RUNNING] sent: false
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Sending task change: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327 -> STOPPED, Known Sent: RUNNING] sent: false
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Error transitioning container module="TaskEngine" task="csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (STOPPED->STOPPED) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (STOPPED->STOPPED),cs_docServer_container (STOPPED->STOPPED),]" container="cs_docServer_container(image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx) (STOPPED->STOPPED) - Exit: 0" state="STOPPED" error="Container not running: fa5de8ea4260647093a89b0524a3ed30ca7fd73862644406541ff21b83cd726a"
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Container fa5de8ea4260647093a89b0524a3ed30ca7fd73862644406541ff21b83cd726a is terminal, stopping stats collection
2017-11-08T07:01:06Z [INFO] Redundant container state change for task csapps_td:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:690021756357:task/0ac25d9a-ddf4-4fe5-9f9b-8dafc1825327, TaskStatus: (STOPPED->STOPPED) Containers: [cs_tomcat_container (STOPPED->STOPPED),cs_docServer_container (STOPPED->STOPPED),]: cs_docServer_container(image1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx) (STOPPED->STOPPED) - Exit: 0 to STOPPED, but already STOPPED
2017-11-08T07:01:14Z [INFO] Saving state! module="statemanager"
```

Comment: I answered a similar question on how to troubleshooting ECS service, could you go through it first? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578949/terraform-ecs-registered-container-instance-is-showing-0/46582013#46582013

Comment: I tried following the link you pointed out, but didnt help much in my case. I am using AWS AMI

Comment: Do you have any logs to share?

Comment: I can share the ecs-agent.log file. But that log file didn't help me much in troubleshooting this issue. Do you expect any particular log files ?

Comment: I have shared the ecs logs in my original post.